# subprocess.Popen("bash file.sh"): how to kill the Bash script and all its background jobs

Tags: python, bash, unix, subprocess

I have a bash script that runs multiple processes in background. I can close them all using Ctrl-C if I run the script in bash terminal.

When I run the script using subprocess.Popen, I cannot close them. I can modify both scripts to get it worked.

I just want to open multiple processes in bash and send them terminate signal when I want to close. I can try different approaches.

Bash Script

```
#!/bin/bash

ping -i 5 google.com &
ping -i 4 example.com &

wait
```

Example Python script:

```
import subprocess
import signal

command = "bash script.sh"
p = subprocess.Popen(command.split())

print("Started")
try:
  p.wait(5) # waits 5 seconds
except:
  print("Kill")

  # These just terminates script.py but pings still working
  #p.kill()
  #p.terminate()
  p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)

p.wait() # does not wait
print("Ended")
```

Comment: Why not passing a timeout to `ping` as well: `ping -t 5 google.com` ?

Comment: Pings are there for demonstration. Those are printing to stdout so I understand if they are still running or not.

Comment: I don't see the symptoms you are reporting.  A Ctrl-C for me kills all processes in either case (shell+ping+ping and py+shell+ping+ping), since all are part of the same process group.  (Note: _ping_ differs from typical commands here in that it installs a SIGINT handler, so the normal semantics of [ignoring SIGINT in asynchronous shell command lists](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11) do not apply).

Comment: @pilcrow I don't want to terminate Python program. I want to terminate rest while Python program is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to catch SIGTERM and kill child processes. Add below code before `wait` in bash file. Also you need to send SIGTERM or use terminate function of Popen object.

```
function trap_sigterm() {
    pkill -SIGINT -P $$  # Kill child processes of $$ (this)
    exit
}

trap trap_sigterm SIGTERM
```